# AKS Upgrade "Operation failed with status: 200. Details: Resource state Failed"

Tags: azure-aks

I recently upgrade my aks service (using Azure Portal) from version v1.9.9 to  1.10.9 but I got this error "Deployment failed. Correlation ID: f19ecf06-205e-4ddb-aeef-de6f6488abd3. Operation failed with status: 200. Details: Resource state Failed.

After that error, my cluster version seems to be 1.10.9 but cluster node version stills be v1.9.9.

How can I revert this status and get my cluster online?

Comment: Can you please share whether you are checking the node and AKS cluster version on Azure portal or using Azure CLI? I would recommend checking both through Azure CLI first. I am trying to understand if there is a portal bug.

If cluster and node versions are different, as seen via Azure CLI, can you retry upgrading AKS cluster using the official doc here, using Azure CLI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/upgrade-cluster

Check if it upgrades both cluster as well as node versions. Let me know if you still see issues.

Comment: I reproduced it and I was able to upgrade to the right version via Azure Portal. Let me know where/how are you checking the node and cluster version.

Comment: Any update? Let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue could be related to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/542). 
It says that AKS can go into failed state if the core quota limit exceeded.
You will have to create and deploy a new cluster and then try upgrading from CLI instead of Portal as it seems that CLI shows the descriptive error if it is because of core quota limit exceeded.